# VB.net 2010 cannot find 'build events' button

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I'm trying to fix my VB 2010 project because it's got that "Cannot access file bin/Debug/… because it is being used by another process" problem, and to fix that I need to add code to the pre-build event.

Everyone says you get to the pre-build event by going to Project>Properties>Compile and then clicking the 'build events' button, but I cannot find it. I literally cannot see the button anywhere. This is all I can see:

[image: Project properties dialog]

Comment: Visual Basic Express doens't support that, so the button isn't visible.

Comment: According to a note in the documentation for [How to: Specify Build Events (Visual Basic)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7xctbe2f(v=vs.100).aspx), "You cannot specify build events from the Visual Basic Express IDE".

Comment: Thank you. i thought i was going insane... I probably will, now that I have to copy everything into a new project......